# Recursive list-constructing parser in Opa

Tags: parsing, recursion, opa

I'd like to write a parser for hashtags. I have been reading the blog
entries on parsing on the opa blog, but they didn't cover recursive
parsers and constructions of lists a lot.

Hashtags are used by some social networks (Twitter, Diaspora*)
to tag a post. They consist of a hash sign (`#`) and an alphanumeric
string such as "interesting" or "funny". One example of a post using
hashtags:

```
Oh #Opa, you're so #lovely! (Are you a relative of #Haskell?)
```

Parsing that would result in `["Opa", "lovely", "Haskell"]`.

I have [tried to do it](https://gist.github.com/1383715), but it doesn't quite what I want. (It could
either only parse one hashtag and nothing else, would fail in an endless
loop or fail because there was input it didn't understand...)
Additionally, here is a [Haskell version](https://gist.github.com/1383667) that implements it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with a remark: by posing question in Haskell-terms you're effectively looking for somebody who knows Opa *and* Haskell hence decreasing chances of finding a person to answer the question ;). Ok, I'm saying it half jokingly as your comments help a lot but still I'd rather see the question phrased in plain English.

I think a solution keeping the structure of the Haskell one would be something like this:

```
parse_tags =
  hashtag = parser "#" tag=Rule.alphanum_string -> tag
  notag = parser (!"#" .)* -> void
  Rule.parse_list_sep(true, hashtag, notag)
```

Probably the main 'trick' is to use the [`Rule.parse_list_sep`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.parser.rules.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.parser.Rule.parse_list_sep) function to parse a list. I suggest you take a look at the [implementation of some functions](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/master/stdlib/core/parser/rules.opa) in the [`Rule`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.parser.rules.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.parser.Rule) module to get inspiration and learn more about parsing in Opa.

Of course I suggest testing this function, for instance with the following code:

```
_ =
  test(s) =
    res =
      match Parser.try_parse(parse_tags, s) with
      | {none} -> "FAILURE"
      | {some=tags} -> "{tags}"
    println("Parsing '{s}' -> {res}")
  do test("#123 #test #this-is-not-a-single-tag, #lastone")
  do test("#how#about#this?")
  void
```

which will give the following output:

```
Parsing '#123 #test #this-is-not-a-single-tag, #lastone' -> [123, test, this, lastone]
Parsing '#how#about#this?' -> FAILURE
```

I suspect that you will need to fine tune this solution to really conform to what you want but it should give you a good head start (I hope).

Comment: Thanks, I changed my post. Don't know if it's better now, though.

Comment: If you ask me -- much better. I understand that I answered your question, tough? Everything clear?

Comment: Mostly. But why do I have to include the dot in `(!"#" .)*`? The [docs](http://doc.opalang.org/#section_syntax_trex) say `.` matches an utf-8 character, but doesn't `!"#"` already match any character that isn't a `#`?

Comment: Nope, it does not. `!` constructs a logical-predicate. That means: it checks whether the given expression *does not* match input at given point and only then continues; but `!`-expression does not consume any input on its own (only does the check).

Answer (score 0):

The following work, just using plain parsers

```
hashtag  = parser "#" tag=Rule.alphanum_string -> tag
list_tag = parser
         | l=((!"#" .)* hashtag -> hashtag)* .* -> l

parsetag(s) = Parser.parse(list_tag, s)

do println("{parsetag("")}")
do println("{parsetag("aaabbb")}")
do println("{parsetag(" #tag1 #tag2")}")
do println("{parsetag("#tag1 #tag2 ")}")
do println("{parsetag("#tag1#tag2 ")}")
```